# GCC doesn't apply vectorization with the O3 compiler flag

Tags: gcc, vectorization

[GCC official autovectorization page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html) says that `-O3` flag should automatically enable vectorization, however, when I inspect the assembly I see that it doesn't work.

I also use the official example provided on the page:

```c
int a[256], b[256], c[256];
foo () {
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<256; i++){
    a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
  }
}
```

The CPU on the machine is `12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12400F`  and `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "avx"` returns the flags which means pretty sure it has vectorization support.

`gcc --version` yields:

`gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0 Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc`

I compile it with `gcc -O3 gccVectorization.c`.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please add your exact GCC version, your OS details, and the exact command(s) used to compile and link your executable.

Comment: The same code is vectorized on Godbolt using the same GCC version. Weird.

Comment: Did you also add `-march=native` or something? (otherwise, it will use at most SSE2 -- and maybe, since the arrays are not necessarily aligned, it does not think it is worth vectorizing)

Comment: @chtz It vectorizes it with that flag but still not sure why it doesn't do it automatically.